# Python CGI End of script output before headers error

Tags: python, cgi

To begin, yes there are other similarly titled questions, no this is not a duplicate.

I'm having a very odd problem when I'm using python and CGI on my webserver.

The following gives the indicated error

```
#! /python34/python
import cgi, Cookie, os
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Output")
```

However, if I don't import Cookie, it works

```
#! /python34/python
import cgi, os
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Output")
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Going to keep saying this: you should not be using CGI. There are much better solutions.

Comment: Meanwhile, have you installed a library called "Cookie"? Which one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, whatever is the default. I didn't manually install anything, I was just following a tutorial and it worked. I'd like to get this working, but what other frameworks would you suggest?

Comment: There is no default library called "Cookie". That's why this doesn't work, because you can't import something that doesn't exist. As far as other alternatives are concerned, it depends on your requirements, but for a microframework look at Flask, or a full-featured one try Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're following is likely for Python 2. The `Cookie` library was renamed to `http.cookies` in Python 3.  If you run `2to3` over your code it should highlight any changes you need to make.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html